# How can I tell if these matrices are congruent?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, quadratic-forms, matrix-congruences

[image]

I am completey lost on this. I know a matrix $B$ is congruent to $A$ if $B = P^\top\!\!AP$ but I tried finding the e-vectors and e-values for $P$ and $P^\top\!$ to spit out $A$ again. I really don't get how you are supposed to find
$$
P = \operatorname{diag} \biggl( \frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}, 4, \frac12 \biggr). 
$$

Am I missing something?

Comment: The Wikipedia article on [matrix congruence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_congruence) will point you to "Sylvester's Law of Inertia", probably the topic this exercise was intended to help reinforce.

Comment: And why do you care about the eigenvalues/vectors of $\;P\;$ ? If two (real, symmetric) matrices are congruent then their number of positive, negative and zero eigenvalues is the same. This makes $\;C\;$ not congruent to $\;A\;$ or $\;B\;$. Now, $\;A,\,B\;$ are congruent because their rank and signature is the same (this is and iff condition). Can you see why?

Comment: Oooh, I get it. C isn't congurent because it has 2 negative e-values compared to A and B's 1.

Comment: If you add a few words at the beginning of your post about where you encountered this problem, I'll undertake to replace your image with the $\LaTeX$ equivalent of the example.